# Wordpress WooCommerce YIT Metaboxes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have taken over maintenance of a Wordpress (4.4.1) site with WooCommerce installed. (Theme is Cheope) - The owner of the site is no longer in contact with the person who maintained it before.

My original question was this, but see Edit below for more info about the actual problem

*My question is, how do you add custom tabs to a product? I can see the previous person has done this to older products, but I can't see where they did it.*

*The custom tabs plugin is not installed, but I can see from an export they are stored as `postmeta` fields with the meta_id = `_custom_tabs` - I can't see anywhere in the admin screen to enter the data.*

**EDIT**

OK I've found where it should be, and that is that the there should be a metabox showing which is registered in `wp-content/themes/cheope/theme/metaboxes.php`, it uses `yit_add_option_metabox()`

However processing isn't even getting to this php file, nor the one that includes this one. `wp-content/themes/cheope/core/metaboxes.php`

Strangely though, when I download the code & database to my own computer (Windows XAMPP server) it works fine.

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/

Comment: @rnevius Yeah I came across that while researching but I don't really want to change anything code wise: the functionality must already be there as it's already working for existing products. I am looking for where the data would be entered in the admin.

Comment: It's not really realistic for us to know what the previous dev may or may not have custom coded. rnevius' link will tell you how to handle custom tabs, which should help you track down what the previous dev did.

Comment: @helgatheviking I realise that, I was asking in case there was some standard way of doing it that I was missing.

Comment: The standard way is the way described in the Woothemes docs that rnevius linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer to this.

In the Cheope theme, the `YIT_Metabox` class has a conflict with other plugins there were installed... i.e.

YIT WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter
YIT WooCommerce Compare
YIT WooCommerce Wishlist

...all of which declare classes called `YIT_Metabox` of their own, and thus prevent the Cheope `YIT_Metabox` from being declared.

Deactivating these plugins brought back the missing Metabox in the product edit page. On a more longer term, I'm not quite so sure... I could rename the `YIT_Metabox` but that might remove my ability to upgrade the theme / WooCommerce

Only newer versions of these plugins pose the conflicts so the previous developer never encountered the issue and at some stage someone upgraded them but I suppose just never noticed.